# Django CMS: Set default placeholder value when page was created

Tags: python, plugins, django-cms

I'm new in Django CMS. When I create my new page, I have to choose placeholders and plugins. Is possible to set all default plugins at `post_save`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with settings by setting the `default_plugins` attribute of the placeholder in `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF`;

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'content': {
        'plugins': ['TextPlugin', 'PicturePlugin'],
        'name': gettext("Content"),
        'language_fallback': True,
        'default_plugins': [
            {
                'plugin_type': 'TextPlugin',
                'values': {
                    'body':'<p>Default text plugin for the `content` placeholder...</p>',
                },
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Then any page with the `content` placeholder will be created with a `TextPlugin` containing `<p>Default text plugin for the`content`placeholder...</p>`

The docs for this can be found here; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#cms-placeholder-conf

Comment: markwalker_, it's possible to define in `default_plugins` some default image? Thank you.

Comment: @DanilaKulakov I haven't tried, but in theory you could certainly include `<img>` tags as part of a text plugin which point at an image URL accessible online.

Comment: Thank you, I will use some default image in HTML template if image doesn't exist.